# How to embed text metadata in html5 canvas images

Tags: html, canvas, png, metadata

When right-clicking on a HTML5 Canvas image, it is offered a "Save As..." option allowing to save the image in PNG format by default.

My question is if it is possible to add text metadata (Title, Author, Description..., etc) to the resulting PNG as described on the [PNG specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html) while generating the drawing.

Comment: not natively, but you can access the arrayBuffer of your file and do whatever you want with it once exported from the canvas.

Comment: Yes but if you are offering images generated on canvas and you want to add meta information to them (for example Copyright, Author) it should be possible to do on the generation process.

Comment: No it is not... didn't wrte specs, but we ca't even set the bits per pixels which would be a greatest utility than text metadata IMO... But once again, png specs are well defined, you seem to know where to find it, so of you've got a few hours, you can implement a metadata editor that you'll call on your exported image.